# Как переопределить все стили media-query

Tags: css

Имеется сторонний набор элементов со своими стилями. Есть ли возможность отменить применение сразу всех стилей для определенного media-query

```
@media (min-width: 37.5rem){
    .wk-header .wk-nav {
        display: block;
        background-color: transparent;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 1.1875rem;
        width: auto;
}
```

а не переопределять каждый из них?
Хотелось бы что-то типа:

```
@media (min-width: 37.5rem){
    .wk-header .wk-nav {
        all-properties: nothing; //чтобы остались определенные раньше свойства
}
```

Comment: нет, _отменить_ вообще ничего нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all: unset;` - сбрасывает все значения.

```
@media (min-width: 37.5rem){
    .wk-header .wk-nav {
        all: unset;
    }
}
```

Comment: уточнил вопрос.  Хотелось бы что-то типа...

Comment: @SIARHEIPAKHUTA, исправила

Answer (score 1):

Есть селектор `*` ко всем элементам, только желательно к каждому стилю добавлять `!important`

```
@media (min-width: 37.5rem){
    * {
        display: block;
        background-color: transparent;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 1.1875rem;
        width: auto;
}
```